# Does <span> have significance to search engines?

Tags: html, seo

The corporate guidlines at my company stipulate that our product names are written in a strange and "wonderful" way [oh how we all love Marketing departments!].

A product name such as "iPhone" is written with the "i" as bold and italic. E.g.

`<b><i>i</i></b>Phone`

I don't want search engines to segment the context of the bold/italic text - for example the above should just be read by a search engine as "iPhone", and not !! **I** !! Phone.

Just want to check if anyone knows for sure that

```
<span class="branding">i</span>Phone
```

Would not apply any additional significance to the "i"?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Afaik, the `<i>` tag is ignored by most search engines, as is `<span>`.

But you could also use the CSS:first-letter pseudo-element. This allows you to style the first letter of a text, so you could write `<span class="branding">iPhone</span`, and then write a css like `.branding:first-letter { font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; }`. This way you got even less risk of search engine problems, and that will make your marketeers happy. :)

See: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pseudo_first-letter.asp

Comment: The first letter suggestion is a great one if you're using the same name often. Support isn't universal, but it's not bad: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter

Answer (score 2):

Type `i phone` into an unnamed popular search engine and you'll get results for `iphone`, `i-phone`, etc. Search engines are pretty clever nowadays. I would say no, it won't have any effect.

Plus, span and other inline tags aren't supposed to represent word boundaries, and search engines shouldn't be treating them as such. If I learned that they do, I'd be very surprised.

Answer (score 0):

<span> is an inline formatting element, and thus has no SEO value at all. HTML tags like <strong> on the other hand have some but very very little SEO significance. Anyway, the crawler will know exactly that you mean iPhone even with the 'i' being between a <span> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Styling is not the only use of Spans and Divs
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div#Semantic_clarity

Answer (score 0):

The  keywords are not intended to have meaning in HTML. It is intended to provide inline differentiation, such as font/color changes, etc.

Some search engines may use supplied  tags to differentiate meanings or importance, but truly it is the CONTENT of the page that is more important than the styling.

,  etc have meaning because they convey a concept, beyond segmentation.